# Different Prices for Frontend and Backend for Same Customer Group

Tags: magento-1.9, php, magento-community

I have a situation where I want to show the different (actual) price on the front-end for same customer group, where as I want to use a discounted price  (assigned to that group) in the back-end when creating order in back-end.

Is this possible?

I have no clue where to start, may be we can detach customer group information when customer logs in from front-end? or use some hook to override the pricing?

Any help will be great!

Comment: Definitely sounds like a good scenario for a custom module...

Answer (score 2):

`sales_quote_add_item` Event will be occurred when you **add product to order from admin**.

Add below code in `config.xml`

```
<adminhtml> 
   <events>
        <sales_quote_add_item>
            <observers>
                <unique_event_name>
                    <class>module/observer</class>
                    <method>productpricechange</method>
                </unique_event_name>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_add_item>
    </events>
 </adminhtml>
```

**Make sure** you are adding `<event>` tag in `<adminhtml>`

In `Observer.php`

```
public function productpricechange($observer) {

    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();

    $new_price = <insert logic>

    $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
    $quote_item->save();
}
```

to get customer detail for your price change logic you can use

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getCustomer();
```

Comment: it works pretty well, just one question, The observer is called only when I add new product, but ignored when I click "Update Items & Qty", I know we're only hooking it with sales_quote_add_item , can you tell me the hook when we add custom price and update??

Comment: You, my friend are a god send!!!!